# Using Ruby Mail Gem to read Email subjects

Tags: ruby, email, pop3

I'm attempting to extract the attachments of emails sent from one of our service providers and save them to a networked drive in order to display the information of a Smashing Dashboard.

I am attempting to use the Mail Gem to do this : 
https://github.com/mikel/mail
http://www.rubydoc.info/github/mikel/mail/Mail

However I'm woefully inexperienced with ruby and especially this specific gem so I'm running into to errors deciphering the emails.

```
###########################################################################
######################## Connect to the POP Server ########################
###########################################################################
require 'mail'
Mail.defaults do
  retriever_method :pop3, :address    => "pop.gmail.com",
                          :port       => 995,
                          :user_name  => '----',
                          :password   => '----',
                          :enable_ssl => true
end

###################################################################
######################## Retrieve the Mail ########################
###################################################################

email = Mail.first    #=> Returns the first unread 

puts email  

if  (email.length > 0)
        puts "New Mail Found"
else
        puts "No New Mail"
end
```

When I run this when there are no new emails everything runs fine, however when there is a new email I get the following error.

> `/var/lib/gems/2.3.0/gems/mail-2.6.6/lib/mail/message.rb:1379`:in
>
> `method_missing`: undefined method `length` for
>
> # (NoMethodError)   from Pop.rb:35:in `main`

This line corrosponds to the if statement. However the github examples very clearly use mail.length to check the number of emails returned and I just have no idea how to go about fixing this.

I'd be grateful of additional eyes checking this for anything obviously wrong, or even some tips to debug it.

Comment: Provide the [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: I believe this is now the min required to replicate the issue, provided the pop details are pointed to an enabled email address.

Comment: `Mail.first` returns the _single_ first unread email. Using of `email.length` probably expects the collection there. Try `Mail.all` instead of `Mail.first`.

Comment: I'm not sure but I guess you have to do `emails = Mail.all` and than check the length of emails or you have to do `email = Mail.first` and check is email equal nil like this `if email == nil`

Comment: I orginally was checking if email was empty but was trying length as an alternative, similar error in either case. While changing the check to if ` !(email==nil)` does allow the code to run in the case of a new email and allows the rest of my code cut from the example to function correctly. It fails in the case of no new emails as whatever is returned from Mail.first even in the event of no new mail must not be nil. 

The puts for email does not output anything into the terminal in the case of no new mail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually found the answer with the aid of this table : https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbe46.png

Changing the if statement to if !(email == []) did the trick

Thanks, everyone for helping me think it through.